# Explicitly specify template template types

Tags: c++, templates, c++-concepts

I'm learning templates. If I mix up the concepts template / template-type / template-argument, please correct me.

I'm trying to write a template function that creates an object and returns it. The type of the object comes from the template argument that has to be explicitly specified.

`result = createObject<ObjectType>();`

This object though is supposed to be a template. A container for example. And the function is supposed to know the type of the object and its template arguments. Ex:

`result = createObject<Container<ElementType>>();`

I've tried to solve it with template template parameter:

```
template <template<class> class ContainerType, class ElementType>
auto createObject()
{
    ContainerType<ElementType> result;

    //do stuff...

    return result;
}

//...

template<typename T>
struct Vector{};

//...

//const auto random_vec = createObject<Vector<float>>(); // ERROR.
  const auto random_vec = createObject<Vector, float>();
```

The second case works, the first doesn't. It says `candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'ContainerType'`.

Is it possible to make it work like the first case? Give it something like `Vector<float>` and it can deduce the `ContainerType` to `Vector` and `ElementType` to `float`? Is it possible to overload or specialize this function so that it handles certain types of containers differently? Should I use concepts?

Comment: isn't "createObject()" just a function and not a class, struct? missing semicolon.

Comment: So `createObject` needs to distinguish the case where the type to create is a specialization of a template rather than a simple type like `int`?

Comment: @DavisHerring Yes.

Comment: Since you asked for corrections: “template function” is outdated terminology.  Since it’s not a kind of function but a kind of template, use “function template” (although the more general “templated function” is also meaningful).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to do decomposition like this is via **partial specialization**, which requires a helper class template:

```
namespace detail {
template<class> struct create;  // undefined
template<template<class T> class C,class T>
struct create<C<T>> {
  static C<T> make() {/* … */}
};
}

template<class T>
T createObject() {return detail::create<T>::make();}
```

The primary template can be defined if you want to support the general case, and other specializations may be added for other kinds of templates like `std::array`.

Comment: Thank you! So far this works. Is the struct needed because functions don't allow partial specialization? How would I add a specialization for `Vector<T>` or `std::array<T>`? A case where I know the primary type is `Vector`, and the element type is `T`.

Comment: @Newline: Right: function templates allow overloading, which is sometimes very similar but doesn’t work at all in this case (absent shenanigans with tag types).  Partial specializations do not have to use `C` in the argument list; you can put `Vector` there (and omit `C` entirely).  `std::array` and `std::map` of course need *more* template parameters, but they work similarly.

Comment: Something like this would have been my answer if I hadn't written my answer in the middle of the night :-) You got my vote.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a type trait to check if the type is instantiated from a template:

```
#include <type_traits>

// trait to check if the type is instantiated from a template
template<typename T>
struct is_template_instance_type : std::false_type {};

template<template<class,class...> class C, class T, class... Rest>
struct is_template_instance_type<C<T,Rest...>> : std::true_type {
    using class_type = C<T,Rest...>;
    using value_type = T;
    // using rest_types = std::tuple<Rest...>; 
};

// Helper variable template - if needed for something later
template<class T>
inline constexpr bool is_template_instance_type_v = is_template_instance_type<T>::value;
```

You could then add overloads:

```
template<class T, class C = is_template_instance_type<T>, class U = typename C::class_type>
auto createObject() {
    U result;
    // typename C::value_type x; // if you need the value type
    
    
    return result;
}

template<template<class,class...> class C, class T, class... Rest>
auto createObject() {
    return createObject< C<T,Rest...> >();
}
```

And it would then work with `Vector<float>`, `Vector, float` but not `float` for example.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Y9x4nbjKj)

Comment: Thank you! I need time to fully understand this.

Comment: @Newline You're welcome. I personally like Davis Herring's answer better although the type trait in my answer could be useful - for something else. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply go like this:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename V = typename T::value_type>
T createObject() 
{
    T t {}; // T will be e.g std::vector<int>
    V v {}; // V will be int

    // do work...
    t.push_back(v++);
    t.push_back(v++);
    // ...work done

    return t;
}
```

Than you can use it like this:

```cpp
int main ()
{
    auto obj1 = createObject<std::vector<int>>();
    auto obj2 = createObject<std::list<double>>();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This means that I have to add a `value_type` definition to my `Vector` and other containers, which is doable. Though I want to have a specialization for `Vector<V>` while also having a general case `T<V>`.